# React updating props from state

Tags: reactjs, spfx

I have a form inside a list.
The list passes a object with a array of topics (another object) on props to the child form, and when I change the values on the state the props values are changed also.
I would like to maintain props in case the user cancels the changes.

```
constructor(props: IMinuteProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      meeting: this.props.meeting,
      EditingThemeDeliberation: undefined
    };
}
```

After Changing the field event:
(EditingThemeDeliberation is the topic being changed)

```
private UpdateDeliberation(event) {
     let { Reunion, EditingThemeDeliberation} = this.state;
     EditingThemeDeliberation.Deliberation = event.target.value;

     Reunion.Themes.splice(Reunion.Themes.findIndex(i => i.Id === 
       this.state.EditingThemeDeliberation.Id), 1,EditingThemeDeliberation);

     // Previous command changes both props and state

     this.setState({ EditingThemeDeliberation: undefined, Reunion: Reunion 
      });
  }
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! It's unclear to me exactly what your question is, could you please clarify? In the meantime, there are two minor issues with your code. In the constructor, you should reference `props` directly, not `this.props`. In the `UpdateDeliberation` method, when you do `EditingThemeDeliberation.Deliberation = event.target.value;` you are changing the value of state without using `setState` which is a big no in React world.

Comment: Thks For the reply. 
I've tried with this and without this on the constructor to se if it changes anything.
Since I made the let { Reunion, EditingThemeDeliberation} = this.state; didn't I create a variable to use and afterwords do the setstate?

Comment: My question is why my props change when I change state. We should not be able to change props from what I understood.

Comment: I'm pretty confident that you are not modifying props anywhere. However, you are improperly modifying state. `let { Reunion, EditingThemeDeliberation} = this.state;` creates pointers in memory to the state object, it doesn't actually create new objects. So later when you do `Reunion.Themes.splice` you improperly modify state since you are changing state outside of a `setState` call

Comment: You might be right on the let thing. I didn't check. I've seen it on so many examples on Microsoft code that I assumed it would create another object. But the change on the object is changing props also. I have a console.log on props and state before and after the splice or any change on the object and it reflects the change on props at the same time. I've changed the change inside the setstate and the result is the same. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I sort of managed to solve the problem. 
Added a clonedeep to the constructor. 
There was also a map on a props object that allowed me to change the props directly (EditingThemeDeliberation was a map of a props). 

Also I'm not completely sure that Let command points to the address of the object. 
`let x = 1; let y= x; x = 2;` should make the result on y to be 2. But it's 1.
I'm very new on react so I might be missing something. 
Again thanks for your help.

Comment: But it behaves like you said on this case.